# How to pass C-r to Vim terminal window?

Tags: vim-windows, terminal

In the Vim terminal I want to be able to search history in bash and ipython but C-r is already bound to basic Vim functionality. Is there any general way to pass this and other characters to the terminal window?

Comment: C-r is not special in a vim-terminal (unless you have tmapped it).

Comment: Weird, I had an error earlier. It's fine now.

Comment: Though my question is now embarrassing, I'll leave it in case some such issue crops up for someone else.